# Site Column & List Column Default values

Tags: powershell, spquery

I have to find the default values of Site columns and Library/list columns using PowerShell script. The site contains 8 to 10 libraries and the default values are different on each library hence I need to get the default values for the columns in different libraries as well as the site column. The following code gives only the Site columns, I need library column details as well.

```
.$defvalue = $field.DefaultValue.
```

Can anyone please help me with the ways to collect this information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Get Default value for Site Column:**

```
$web= Get-SPWeb http://siteurl
$field = $web.Fields["FieldName"]
$devaultvalue = $field.DefaultValue
```

**Get Default value for List / Library Column**

```
$web= Get-SPWeb http://siteurl
$list = $web.Lists["listname"]
$FieldName = $list.Fields["FieldName"]
$defaultvalue= $FieldName.DefaultValue
```